# Loading PCL sourced HTML page in Cross Browser project (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin to support

- Android
- iOS
- Windows 8.1
- WPF

I can create a PCL project that each of those platforms can see  from their platform specific project.

What I want to be able to do is host a HTML page and associated javascript files in the PCL.

All the examples I have seen for loading Local Html files are when there is a copy of the HTML in each platform specific project. I don't want 4 copies of the HTML I want one copy in the PCL.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

We tried to do the same thing a few months ago and as far as I remember we couldn't. The solution for us to make it work was downloading (or extracting in your case) html files to the local directory for each platform using PCLStorage nuget and load directly from local path with custom renderers.

We used custom renderers for each platform for WebView instead of crossx webview. One thing to note that instead of using UIWebView you must use WKWebView if you're targeting iOS9+.

Simply pass your main directory of html files to each renderer and try native controls to use local content. Unfortunately xamarin's crossx WebView does not provide flexible actions when it comes to local content.